# How to get specific (unique code) word from string on php?

Tags: php, regex

I have text string like :

> [CLOSED][#SD_1623834126_001] lorem ipsum ?

and question is, how I get unique code/my ticket number #SD_xxxx ?

Please help me guys, thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `preg_match_all` with the regex pattern `#\w+` to capture all hashtag matches in your input:

```php
$input = "[CLOSED][#SD_1623834126_001] lorem ipsum ?";
preg_match_all("/#\w+/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[0][0]);  // #SD_1623834126_001
```